# Hangout chat bot - get message name (spaces/xx/message/yy) of my bot's message in order to update it

Tags: google-hangouts

I have a hangout chat bot on a google cloud function.
I'd like to use the message.update endpoint of the rest api to update one of the message the bot sent earlier to a user.

Problem is I can't figure out how to get the message id (name) of the message my bot just sent.

For instance, if my bot sent `{ text: "hello" }` and later i want to change the text to something else.

In my context, whenever a user sends a message to the bot, it call's my function and the bot replies whatever I send back from the function.

So when I send the "hello" message, im not using the api, juste replying to the request.

Is there a way to get the name of the message in this context or must I switch to regular api calls in order to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about cloud function but, You will get it in regular API or you can use API Libraries, To answer your question, When you create a message using spaces.messages.create it returns message id in response, you can use that message Id in update message API.

Check below response from create message API,

```
{
  "name": "spaces/u********E/messages/N*********M.N*********M", **//last one is messageId**

        "sender": {
            "name": "users/1***************2",
            "displayName": "",
            "type": "BOT"
        },
        "text": "hello world",
        "cards": [],
        "previewText": "",
        "annotations": [],
        "thread": {
            "name": "spaces/u********E/threads/N********M"
        },
        "space": {
            "name": "spaces/u********E",
            "type": "DM",
            "displayName": ""
        },
        "fallbackText": "",
        "argumentText": "Hello World",
        "createTime": "2019-03-07T07:44:06.430607Z"
    }
```

**Also refer discovery document.**

```
https://chat.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1
```

Here you will get implementation of create message using library.

```
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1123#issuecomment-396111871
```